# ruby Thread, kill vs terminate vs exit

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exit, kill, terminate

Ruby newby here and I am currently working with Ruby 2.3.0 and was working with a threaded gem and using Threads myself. I was looking at the ruby documentation and was curious if there was any nuances between the thread instance methods #kill, #exit and #terminate (the documentation groups them to the same description) or if they are just 3 names for the exact same code for convenience? I tried searching for a bit for answers but couldn't find any satisfying answers.

Answer (score 3):

When methods are grouped like that in the docs (a short list of method names, followed by one description), then they are aliases of each other. They share the same source code.